# `rails new my_app` returns "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, gemfile

I tried creating a new Rails app, and got this error:

```
% bundle exec rails new my_app
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

I tried running `bundle` and got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just leave off the `bundle exec` part of the command:

```
% bundle exec rails new my_app 
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

% rails new my_app
      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
      (etc.)
```

In the case of generating a new rails app (something that I've only done 3-4 times in several years as a full-time Rails developer), there is no Gemfile yet...just like the error suggests. `rails new my_app` is probably the only command in the Rails environment that *can't* run under bundler.

This may be a particular gotcha if you've got an `alias rails=bundle exec rails` in your shell, or if your fingers are just trained to always type `bundle exec` for rails commands. In this case, you could remove that alias (`unalias rails`), but it's probably better to bypass the alias just this once by enclosing it in quotes:

```
"rails" new my_app
      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      (etc.)
```

Answer (score 1):

what about :

- rails new app_name
- cd app_name
- bundle

Comment: The problems was including, `bundle exec` on the `rails new` command.

Comment: that's why i suggest to remove bundle exec